# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop')

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

[image: 1]

I need help with bootstrap, javascript and jquery, I'm using js to create a modal but after that my js can't receive the submission of the modal I created

```js
$("#forgetPass").click(function() {
    var id = "forgetPassword";
    var tittle = "Recuperar senha"
    var body = `<form>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="PasswordfloatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
      <label for="floatingInput"> <i class="bi bi-envelope-at-fill"></i> Digite seu email</label>
      <div class="text-start">
      <p id="pass_resul"></p>
    </div>
    </div>
  `
    var button = `<button class="text-end btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="password_submit" type="submit">Enviar</button></form>`
    create_modal(id, tittle, body, button)
})

function create_modal(id, title, body, button) {
    var modal = document.createElement("div");

    modal.setAttribute("class","modal fade");
    modal.setAttribute("id",id);
    modal.setAttribute("tabindex","-1");
    modal.setAttribute("role","dialog");
    modal.setAttribute("aria-labelledby",id);
    modal.setAttribute("aria-hidden","true");

    modal.innerHTML = `
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title"><span ></span>`+title+`</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="modal_body_`+id+`">
    `+body+`
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    `+button+`
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>`;

    document.body.appendChild(modal);

    $('#'+id).modal('show');

    $('#'+id).on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#'+id).remove();
    });
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.10.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
  <form>
    <img class="mb-4" src="../assets/brand/bootstrap-logo.png" alt="" width="150" height="80">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal text-start">Login</h1>

    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com">
      <label for="floatingInput"> <i class="bi bi-envelope-at-fill"></i> Digite seu email</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <button class="btn-show-pass"><i class="bi bi-eye-slash-fill"></i></button>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="floatingPassword" placeholder="Password">
      <label for="floatingPassword"><i class="bi bi-key-fill"></i> Digite sua senha</label>
    </div>
    <div class="text-start">
      <p id="resul"></p>
    </div>
    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit">Entrar</button>
    <div class=" mt-4">
      <a class="text-decoration-none" href="#" id="forgetPass" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#forgetPassword"><p>Esqueceu a senha?</p></a> 
    </div>
  </form>

</main>
```

I'm using a submit button to create a modal in the dom, but I can't use the submit button from the modal I just created

I don't know why this is happening, I use this function in another code and it works perfectly